# Understanding explicit vs implicit variable declaration in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class named Item, I am performing LINQ queries on this class but I have noticed that when I try using the `group` operator:

I do not have access to the `IEnumarable` interface extension methods like `key`.

Something like:

```
       var groupByQuery =
            from item in items
            group item by item.ItemType[0];

        foreach (Item item in groupByQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
            ...
        }
```

will produce the error:

```
`Error  1   'ProductCatalog.Item' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'ProductCatalog.Item' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
```

I need to change it to:

```
foreach (var item in groupByQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
            ...
        }
```

to get it to work. I just need to understand why this is happening.Something in my head tells me this has something to do with the types of `Item` and the type `Key` returns, but that's about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply use IntelliSense and mouseover `item` of the `item in groupByQuery` line, you will see the difference in these types.

Using `var item` will use the type generated by the group by expression, which is `IGrouping<T, Item>` (I wrote `T` here because I don't know the type of `ItemType[0]`).

Using `Item item` will cast it to an `Item`, as you would expect. As the error describes, the class `Item` does not implement `Key`. You can do this explicitly in your class if you choose to do so, but this may not be the best approach. The reason is that generally when you use `group by` you are returning a group of `Item`, which is different than a single instance of `Item` (assuming there will be multiple `Items` with `ItemType[0]`). Therefore you may prefer to use a new class (such as `ItemGroup`) that implements `IGrouping<T, Item>` or rethink the query.

Answer (score 0):

A group query returns an IEnumerable of groups. A group has a Key and an IEnumerable. So, your for loop could be like this:

```
foreach (var group in groupByQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", item);
    }
}
```

---

Your question is more about `foreach` then. `foreach` would seem to be equivalent of a `for` or `while` indexing from the first element to the last (or `break`). With your `foreach (Item item in groupByQuery)`, it would seem to start like this:

```
Item item = groupByQuery.ElementAt(0);
```

However, that won't compile because a group is not of type Item.

The non-intuitive—but completely documented—thing about `foreach` is that the compiler translates it as if it was coded like this:

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded-statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        … // Dispose e
    }
}
```

where V is the given or implicit type of the loop control variable. It performs a cast, which can fail at runtime, even though you'd prefer a compiler error. Casting would be our intent for non-generic IEnumerable. Effectively, there is no `foreach` for `IEnumerable<T>`, it degrades to a `foreach` for `IEnumerable`.

If you want to know why, see [Eric Lippert's blog](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/).

Comment: I already know how to do this, Tom. I think you need to re-read my question.